# What is the dict iteration indexing method?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I hope the code explains my question better:

```
 dic={'one':'root', 'two':'leaf', 'three':'tree', 'four':'fruit'}
 for n in dic.keys():
     n = dic.get(n)
     print(n)
```

Output:

```
fruit
leaf
root
tree
```

Can anyone explain please, what is the logic behind this kind of sequence in output?
I know, Dict does not support indexing. Then how does it work? why 'fruit' is at first and 'leaf' second?

Comment: I got this as out put : ```root
leaf
tree
fruit```

Comment: Strange! That should be. Then why it is different in my case? I tried it in general CMD of my windows.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are ordered according to how the keys were inserted starting in Python 3.6: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Prior to Python 3.6, the ordering of keys in dictionaries was not specified, and cannot be relied upon.

Comment: I declared new dict variable with same keys and values. The same thing happening.

Comment: @RafiSarker why did you expect a different thing to happen?

Comment: May be I did not get well about the 'how the keys were inserted'. assigning all values at once. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @RafiSarker: In Python 3.6 and later, when you create a dict using the syntax like `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}` with the values in it from the beginning, that ordering is preserved.  Prior to 3.6, the ordering is not preserved.